# How do i compare these two dictionaries (one of them which is nested)? [Python]

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries here that i would like to compare

```
dict1 = {
    'Alice': {'AGATC': '2', 'AATG': '8', 'TATC': '3'},
    'Bob': {'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'},
    'Charlie': {'AGATC': '3', 'AATG': '2', 'TATC': '5'},
}

dict2 = {'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'GATA': '2', 'TATC': '5', 'GAAA': '3'}
```

How can i compare these two to see that the values that are present shows clearly Bob has all same values? thank u

Comment: `shows clearly Bob has all same values` ...? Bob has no `'GAAA': '3'`

Comment: nor `'GATA': '2'`...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of all (checking if all Bob's keys in `dict2` and the values are equal):

```
for user, items in dict1.items():
    result = all(dict2.get(k) == v for (k, v) in items.items())
    print("%s: %s" % (user, result))
```

Output:

```
Charlie: False
Bob: True
Alice: False
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank you very much.
edit: can you explain line 2 abit more?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't clear enough, try to clarify what the error or what you expected exactly.

If you mean that you want to check if an item of a dictionary of 'dict1' exists in an item of a dictionary 'dict2' but not exactly the same value you can try this:

```
dict1 = {
    'Alice': {'AGATC': '2', 'AATG': '8', 'TATC': '3'},
    'Bob': {'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5','jjj':'5'},
    'Charlie': {'AGATC': '3', 'AATG': '2', 'TATC': '5'},
}

dict2 = {'Bob': {'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'}}
for i in dict1:
    for j in dict2:
        if set(dict2[j].items()).issubset(set(dict1[i].items())):
                print(i)
```

The output:

```
>>> Bob
```

But, if you want to check if it exists exactly with the same values, you simply add if statement:

```
dict1 = {
    'Alice': {'AGATC': '2', 'AATG': '8', 'TATC': '3'},
    'Bob': {'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5','jjj':'5'},
    'Charlie': {'AGATC': '3', 'AATG': '2', 'TATC': '5'},
}

dict2 = {'Bob': {'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'}}
for i in dict1:
    for j in dict2:
        if set(dict2[j].items()).issubset(set(dict1[i].items())) and dict2[j] == dict1[i]:
                print(i)
```

There is no output:

```
>>>
```

Comment: sorry, i deleted off my question due to formatting. yes, my question is how to compare two dictionaries, if 'dict1' exists in an item of a dictionary 'dict2' but not exactly the same value. Thank u, let me try your solution.